# Apple pay : This device cannot make payments?

Tags: ios, iphone-6, applepay

i am getting this "**Error**" message every time tapping on apple pay icon in my app. **i have a testing environment with merchant identifier**. 
The thing **i just want to do is to present the payment sheet** (i did not entered credit card in passbook.i don't need credit cared entered for presenting sheet i think). **Please help!!**

Comment: You have to enable Apple Pay before it will display the sheet.

Comment: must have to enter credit card info in passbook (to enable apple pay) ?? 
i this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/87300/apple-pay-tutorial
he didn't said regarding this. i am confused :(

Comment: I did a quick review of the tutorial.  In some of screen shots you can a CHASE FREEDOM credit was added to the phone.  Which Payment Platform are you going to use?

Comment: If you're getting a specific error message, please post it. Also, the payment sheet will not present if no cards are configured on the device.

Comment: @aednichols i entered the card on m iphone 6+. now it return true on +(Bool) canMakePayment; but return nil on PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController :( i have a valid entitlement but still giving this error

Comment: @Ali please edit your question and include your entire Apple Pay setup code. It is nigh impossible to reason out why the view controller is `nil` otherwise.

Comment: @aednichols thanku bro i figured out the problem its working now :)

Comment: @Ali and what was the solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @allthewayapps just enabled Apple pay in iPhone.